# Find nearest previous Higher Pivot Point then lowest Pivot Point since then till Current Price (Pine)

Tags: pine-script, trading

I have found the TradingView "Pivot Point HL" built in Pine script, which gives me the pivot points. I am trying to write a Pine script that:

1. Find the nearest previous Higher Pivot Point then lowest Pivot Point since then till Current Price.
2. Draw Fibonacci Retracement between these two points.

See below pseudo algorithm I wrote that I am trying to achieve:

```
 - LOOP Lookback starting from nearest HIGH pivot point (greater than current price) and keep going to the higher ones
      - For each, Lookahead from that point and find the LOWEST price hit so far
           - Calculate a specific Fib level for them and return these two Pivot Points and draw that Fib level if: CURRENT PRICE is BELOW that level.
```

See attached. The LOOKBACK would first try Pivot 1 GREEN with 1 RED, fail then try Pivot 2 GREEN with 2 RED, fail then try Pivot 3 GREEN with Pivot 2 RED, succeed, so we found our two points to draw the Fibonacci retracement from Pivot 3 GREEN to Pivot 2 RED.

Is this achievable in Pine? Any script or useful Pine snippets you can point me to, to help me code this LOOKBACK and LOOKFORWARD?

[image: Pivots]

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: @BarisYakut Is this achievable in Pine? Any script or useful Pine snippets you can point me to, to help me code this LOOKBACK and LOOKFORWARD?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to LOOKBACK in PineScript, but it is not possible to LOOKFORWARD.
If you want to save a value, that you can access later, then you need to save it to a **var** variable.

Here is a post I answered last summer, where I explain **var** variables in more detail.
[explaining var variable in post](https://pinescripters.net/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=356&p=642#p642)

Here is also a post from last summer, where I show how to save Pivot Points to **var** variables. [saving to most recent pivot point in var variable](https://pinescripters.net/viewtopic.php?f=22&t=352&p=635#p635)